# How to stop Excel from changing the Active Sheet after “Refresh all”?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 queries (Power Query) in my Excel file that bring information from other different files in table format and in another worksheet I have a button that executes the `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` function.

```
Sub ButtonRefreshData()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

**The problem is:** Every time I update my queries, either through the button or Excel's own Refresh/Refresh all tool, my Active Worksheet is changed to the tables that I'm refreshing.

I also tried to set the sheet that I want as active after the refresh with something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Activate`, but no results.

[image: Excel changes my active sheet after refresh all]

How can I update my queries without changing my active sheet?
I'm currently using **Excel 2016**.

**What I'm trying to do:** I want the user to be able to update the data in the worksheet, but I don't want him to have direct access to the tables/data in the worksheets that will be hidden. The user must remain in the "main worksheet", which has the update button.

Comment: Why not just set the sheet you want as active at the end of the code?

Comment: @braX I tried and it didn't work. It seems that Excel changes the active worksheet automatically after the code execution, even though I put `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Activate` after the `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`

Comment: Maybe the refresh code is getting retriggered then? You did not include any of your code so it's anyone's guess what the problem could be, but that's how you do it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should've made that clear, but the only code that I'm using is `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`. That's it. I did try to set the sheet that I want after that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @braX I don't think that's the case. Having `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Activate` after 'ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll' did work, which lead Excel to activate my desired sheet. However, after the code execution, Excel automatically set the refreshing sheets as active. [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/mjgjzq2.gif) a .GIF about the problem.

Comment: Do you have any other code in the workbook — for example a `PivotTableUpdate` event that might be getting triggered by the `RefreshAll`?  Stepping through line-by-line with F8 might help?

Comment: @Chronocidal There is no other code in the file, but I ended up finding that: If I Step Into code with F8, Excel actually respects my `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet").Activate` after `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`. However, if I run it normal with F5, it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried my latest idea with the extra sub?

Comment: @davi_m Do you have Background Refresh enabled or disabled for PowerQuery?

Comment: @Chronocidal It's currently enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another user who had a similar problem reported that he was unable to resolve the issue and he attributed the cause to the version of Excel he was using, which turned out to be the same as mine.

In this sense, I assume that the cause is some bug in the version: **Excel 2016 - 16.0.4266.1001**

If you are having the same problem, please try to use newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

### Activate the Previously Active Sheet

- I couldn't reproduce your issue. I created two queries but both of them didn't change the `ActiveSheet`. Here are two ideas, the second being a bit too extreme i.e. it may hang or crash Excel. Your feedback is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Possibly get rid of all related to `ash` and just use the explicit `Sheet1.Select` after `twRefresh`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet
    twRefresh
    ash.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub twRefresh
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

**Initial Ideas**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    DoEvents
    ash.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub Test2()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Application.Visible = False
    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    DoEvents
    ash.Select

ProcExit:
    Application.Visible = True
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: `Test1()` didn't work, Excel still changing the active sheet. About '`Test2()`, the code ran for a few minutes, but apparently Excel ended up not responding. I appreciate the ideas.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Here's another one. try to write a new sub (in the same module) containing only `Sub twRefresh():ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll :End Sub` and in the first solution use `twRefresh` instead of `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`.

Comment: Why not simplify to `With ActiveSheet: ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll: .Select: End With`, and remove the need for `ash`, while still dynamically remembering which sheet you started on?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Unfortunately I had no results.

Comment: @Chronocidal: Believe it or not, I even started writing it like this, but I changed my mind. I guess I don't know 100% what `With ActiveSheet` does and if it could get 'challenged' somehow (I trust the variable). The other day, Sid said that when you do `Workbooks.Add`, you shouldn't continue with `ActiveWorkbook` but with `Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`. What's that all about?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Even though it says `ActiveSheet`, it retains remains the same sheet all the way through the `With`, even if you activate another sheet in the middle.  The thing with `Workbooks.Add` is about making sure you use the new workbook, in case it opens in the background and doesn't get set as the `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Do you know any case (reason) when the newly added workbook would open in the background?